# Add custom OS images to bochs on iphone?

Tags: iphone, applications, customization

im trying to get DSL (Damn Small Linux) to work on the iphone version of bochs but i cant figure out how to configure the os.ini file, please help?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! This isn't really a question about the Apple part of your setup (hardware or iOS) it's a question about Linux. I recommend that you ask on the Stack Exchange site dedicated to Linux, http://unix.stackexchange.com/. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use ifile, click "os.ini" then click "text editor".

It works for me!!!

Comment: i know that but i don't know what to put in!